I can't integrate css to Chatbro
How can i make chatHeaderBackgroundColor: '#7367f0', only for body[data-style="dark-layout"] otherwise i want to make it #ffffff
css didn't effect, I spent hours and a lot of work on it but i could change the color only with js.
here is documentation in case you need to understand things better: https://www.chatbro.com/en/documentation/
<?php
    if (isset($user)) {
    
        // Configure here
        $admins = ['Leila', 'Paul'];
        $secretKey = '7adg9c6-da74-4157-1958-fd0sd83s79d4';
        $encodedChatId = '74mSl';
        $siteDomain = 'earncrypto.com'; // without https or http and www
        // END
    
        $siteUserFullName = $user['username'];
        $siteUserProfileUrl = site_url('admin/users/details/' . $user['id']);
        $permissions = [];
        $permissionsDisplay = '';
    
          if (!in_array($siteUserFullName, $admins)) {
            $permissions = [];
            $permissionsDisplay = "[]";
           $siteUserFullName .= '<span class="vie-level" data-level="' . $user['level'] . '"></span>';
            $siteUserAvatarUrl = site_url('/assets/images/chat/user_chat.png');
            $siteUserFullNameColor = '#9f87ba';
            if ($user['level'] >= 20) {
                $siteUserFullNameColor = '#D65DB1';
            }
            if ($user['level'] >= 50) {
                $siteUserFullNameColor = '#FF6F91';
            }
            if ($user['level'] >= 100) {
                $siteUserFullNameColor = '#B05C00';
            }
            if ($user['level'] >= 200) {
                $siteUserFullNameColor = '#4E8397';
            }
            if ($user['level'] >= 500) {
                $siteUserFullNameColor = '#C34A36';
            }
    
        } else {
            $permissions = ['ban', 'delete'];
            $permissionsDisplay = "['ban', 'delete']";
            $siteUserAvatarUrl = site_url('/assets/images/chat/admin.png');
            $siteUserFullNameColor = '#ffcc00'; // Gold color for admins
            $siteUserFullName .= ' ★'; // Add star for admins
        }
        $siteUserExternalId = $user['id'];
    
        if ($siteDomain != 'demo.com') {
    ?>
        <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;1,400;1,500;1,600&display=swap');
    
        body {
            font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        }
    
        .chatbro_message_name.admin {
            color: #ffcc00; /* Gold color for admins */
            font-weight: bold;
        }
          span.vie-level {
        display: block; /* Make it block-level */
        padding: 10px; /* Example padding */
        background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Example background color */
        border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Example border */
        /* Add more styles as needed */
    }
        </style>
        <script id="chatBroEmbedCode">
                function ChatbroLoader(chats, async) {
                    async = !1 !== async;
                    var params = {
                            embedChatsParameters: chats instanceof Array ? chats : [chats],
                            lang: navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage,
                            needLoadCode: 'undefined' == typeof Chatbro,
                            embedParamsVersion: localStorage.embedParamsVersion,
                            chatbroScriptVersion: localStorage.chatbroScriptVersion
                        },
                        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
                    xhr.withCredentials = !0;
                    xhr.onload = function() {
                        eval(xhr.responseText);
                    };
                    xhr.onerror = function() {
                        console.error('Chatbro loading error')
                    };
                    xhr.open('GET', '//www.chatbro.com/embed.js?' +
                        btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(params)))), async);
                    xhr.send();
                }
                /* Chatbro Widget Embed Code End */
                ChatbroLoader({
                    encodedChatId: '<?= $encodedChatId ?>',
                    siteDomain: '<?= $siteDomain ?>',
                    chatHeaderBackgroundColor: '#7367f0',
                    showChatShadow: 'true',
                    siteUserExternalId: '<?= $siteUserExternalId ?>',
                    siteUserFullName: '<?= $siteUserFullName ?>',
                    siteUserAvatarUrl: '<?= $siteUserAvatarUrl ?>',
                    siteUserProfileUrl: '<?= $siteUserProfileUrl ?>',
                    siteUserFullNameColor: '<?= $siteUserFullNameColor ?>',
                    permissions: <?= $permissionsDisplay ?>,
                    signature: '<?= md5($siteDomain . '' . $siteUserExternalId . '' . $siteUserFullName . '' . $siteUserAvatarUrl . '' . $siteUserProfileUrl . '' . $siteUserFullNameColor . '' . implode('', $permissions) . '' . $secretKey) ?>'
                });
            </script>
    
    <?php }
    } ?>


I would set it to ffffff then update it with js... if the implementation here is correct. If that is your real secret key you should get a new one.
